# Getting Layout name of the Activity using Accessibility Service in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am trying to create an app to get the Package name, Activity name and Activity Layout Name (XML)of other apps. For this purpose I am using Accessibility Service to get the WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED of the foreground window.

**What I have Achieved?**

I am able to get package name and activity name of other apps using Accessibility service.

**What I am not able to Achieve!**

I have tried almost all the possible solutions to get the layout name of the Activity, but unfortunately I am failing each and every successive attempts.

**What I have tried so far:**

STEP 1:

Created **accessibilityservice.xml** under **res/xml** folder as like below

```
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
```

STEP 2:

Created **WindowChangeDetectingService.java** Service class and logged package name and activity as like below

```
    import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
    import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ComponentName;
    import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
    import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;

    import java.util.List;

    public class WindowChangeDetectingService extends AccessibilityService {

        @Override
        protected void onServiceConnected() {
            super.onServiceConnected();

            //Configure these here for compatibility with API 13 and below.
            AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
            config.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
            config.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
                //Just in case this helps
                config.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS;

            setServiceInfo(config);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

            if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
                if (event.getPackageName() != null && event.getClassName() != null) {
                    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
                        event.getPackageName().toString(),
                        event.getClassName().toString()

                    );


                    Log.i("AccessPackagename",  event.getPackageName().toString());
                    Log.i("AccessgetClassName",  event.getClassName().toString());

                }
            }
        }
}
```

STEP 3: Registered WindowChangeDetectingService created in manifest.xml as like below

```
<service
            android:name=".WindowChangeDetectingService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice"/>
        </service>
```

**OUTPUT**: (Retrieved from Logcat)

```
08-18 12:51:45.430 11206-11206/com.takeoffandroid.screenlog I/AccessPackagename: com.takeoffandroid.screenlog
08-18 12:51:45.430 11206-11206/com.takeoffandroid.screenlog I/AccessgetClassName: com.takeoffandroid.screenlog.MainActivity
```

**My Requirement: (Expected Output)**

```
08-18 12:51:45.430 11206-11206/com.takeoffandroid.screenlog I/AccessPackagename: com.takeoffandroid.screenlog
    08-18 12:51:45.430 11206-11206/com.takeoffandroid.screenlog I/AccessgetClassName: com.takeoffandroid.screenlog.MainActivity

--------------------------------------------------------------------    --------------------------------------------------------------------

    08-18 12:51:45.430 11206-11206/com.takeoffandroid.screenlog I/AccessgetLayoutName: activity_main.xml //Should be capable to read the layout name of the MainActivity

--------------------------------------------------------------------   --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have been working on this requirement since past two days but am not able to find any method or ways to do it so in Android using Accessibility Service. Any help or suggestions will be really helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your service config to include the view id names in your accessibility node infos.

```
<accessibility-service
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagReportViewIds|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
```

The important change here is this:

> android:accessibilityFlags="flagReportViewIds|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"

or even more specifically this portion:

> flagReportViewIds

Also, you should not include your onServiceConnected function. You're modifying all of the configuration you're doing in your service_config xml file. You're also not quite doing it correctly. Creating a new service info is dangerous, as you're unlikely to populate all of the fields that matter. This line:

```
AccessibilityServiceInfo config = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
```

Should be this:

```
AccessibilityServiceInfo config = getServiceInfo()
```

And then modify that! Although, seriously, don't do this, just rely on service_config XML props.

Once you have the proper configuration, you should be able to do this:

```
someAccessibilityNodeInfo.getViewIdResourceName()
```

Which is the ID that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am not able to fetch getViewIdResourceName method from AccessibilityServiceInfo. I was trying to use getRootInActiveWindow().getViewIdResourceName(), but it was throwing NullPointerException

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.getViewIdResourceName()' on a null object reference

Comment: If this is the case, you have done the configuration portion of this incorrectly OR the view does not have a resource name. Not all views do. In fact, the root view never will.  The root view is an Android OS owned container for your activity. Your "Activity's" root is a little farther down the hierarchy.

Comment: @Chandru Were you able to resolve that? I am looking for the same.

Comment: I am also unable to get viewIdResourceName, it's giving me null @MobA11y

Comment: This answer is ancient in Android years. Null may in fact be the expected value for most cases in a Compose Dominated environment.